# How to DRY this snippet of Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

This is bothering me. It doesn't look too DRY. What would be a better implementation? As an aside, how come this ActiveRecord finder doesn't throw an exception when record is not found, but .find does?

```
  def current_account
    return @account if @account
    unless current_subdomain.blank?
      @account = Account.find_by_host(current_subdomain)
    else
      @account = nil
    end
    @account
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would code this like

```
def current_account
  @account ||= current_subdomain.blank? ? nil : Account.find_by_host(current_subdomain)
end
```

As for the exceptions, find_by dynamic methods return `nil` instead of throwing an exception.  If you want an exception, use the `find` with `:conditions`:

```
def current_account
  @account ||= current_subdomain.blank? ? nil : Account.find(:first, :conditions => {:host  => current_subdomain})
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def current_account  
  @account ||= current_subdomain && Account.find_by_host(current_subdomain)
end
```

If a record isn't found, the dynamic `find_by` methods return nil, `find_by_all` returns an empty array.

Comment: But .find_by_host should not be called if current_subdomain is an empty string. 

And if the && fails, what will be @account be assigned? false?

Comment: However this fails if current_subdomain is "". "" evaluates to true in boolean context. Should be `!current_subdomain.blank?`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def current_account
  @account ||= Account.find_by_host(current_subdomain) unless current_subdomain.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def current_account  
  @account ||= current_subdomain.present? && Account.find_by_host(current_subdomain)
end
```

`#present?` will handle `nil` and empty strings